# How to override CartItemInterface class in in my custom model?

Tags: magento2, cart, api, plugin, preference

I have to add 2 new methods getter and setter in CartItemInterface but i am facing issues.
Basically I have added a new column in quote item table and now I want to add this column in cart api.

Please let me know how I can achieve that ?
I'm using magento2 version 2.3.

Comment: You cannot override interface classes, create your own custom interface.
Magento 2 does not allow us to override the interfaces.

Comment: What if I have to add a new method in existing interface ? I mean I want to add extra method in magento2 core interface. What is the best approach ?

Comment: You can use Extension attributes, it is used to extend functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for adding extension attributes in extension_attributes.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
<attribute code="custom_attribute_flag" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Comment: I have added extension attribute but it doesn't appear in my quote item table so i have added it by declarative schema and now I want to add it in cart API payload but when i added it and hit the API it gives me an error like "custom_column" doesn't have accessor method. After doing some R&D i came to know that there should be a getter and setter method for custom_column and these are written in cart item interface which is magent core class and I can't change it directly. Please let me know how I can achieve that ?

Comment: Yes, It give you error.
You should set the value by extension attribute. Please check this tutorial:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Extension Attribute gives you declarative way of extending existing interfaces.
You can start by creating,
etc/extension_attributes.xml
Follow this link ,
https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-use-extension-attributes-in-magento-2/
For reference.

Comment: I have added extension attribute but it doesn't appear in my quote item table so i have added it by declarative schema and now I want to add it in cart API payload but when i added it and hit the API it gives me an error like "custom_column" doesn't have accessor method. After doing some R&D i came to know that there should be a getter and setter method for custom_column and these are written in cart item interface which is magent core class and I can't change it directly. Please let me know how I can achieve that ?